Why is a constant needed while picking up an image from gallery in android?
I want to know why do we need to have a constant in the process of selecting an image from gallery in android? Like why do we compare it to the request code afterwards?
I have searched for explanations from various platforms but couldn't grasp the idea

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
